# Android: How do you change the WebView Scrollbar color?

Tags: android, webview, colors, scrollbar

I can't seem to find a way to change the colour of the scrollbar in the webview.

The current default color is a grey color. When I change the background of the webview to black, the scrollbar is not visible.

Need a way to make it white or whatever color.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can with android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/youdrawable

yourdrawable is:

```
<gradient android:startColor="#66C0C0C0" android:endColor="#66C0C0C0"
    android:angle="45"/>

<corners android:radius="6dp" />
```

Comment: For some reason setting that property at runtime is not working. You need to load it from resource using inflate.